# Is it possible to run a HTML 5 video in a separate thread?

Tags: javascript, multithreading

I know web workers allow limited access to additional threads when coding in Javascript.

I was wondering if anybody knows of a method of running HTML 5 videos in a separate thread?  I would imagine this is very difficult if we want to retain control of that video from the original thread?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible, because you don't have access to the DOM from within a webworker (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers). Thus, you can't draw the video-frames to the screen in any way.

Comment: Not at the moment. Webworkers are the only way to achieve concurrency in the browser. Maybe Webassembly will add more advanced concurrency-features in the future.